How to change location and rotation of view in blender evenly
From Orthogonal view (eg. hitting 1 on the numpad) I want my view in Blender (not the camera) to change the position in terms of location and rotation so that it rotates both along a fixed radius and adjusts its own rotation to follow that as if it was walking on the surface of a barrel.
Each step in changing the view should be equal so that it arrives back at its initial location after say 64 steps.
The picture attached is just for concept illustration, where the camera stands for each of my instances of view in blender and how I want to change it by step. The blue arrows indicating the direction of the view.


This would probably require you to write a custom build of Blender in C++. Not only that but I don't exactly understand how this would be preferable in alot of scenarios. What if you're really close to the object? Does the camera slide out to that fixed radius before rotating? Seems disorienting. Is the rotation pivot gonna be the cursor? world origin? whatevers selected? Seems like it only works if you essentially never move the camera yourself.

I just want the right view as an orientation guide in my modeling process. The problem is I have two objects that are supposed to fit onto one another (after 3d-printing) but I designed it too tight so I need to increase the minimal distance between object 1 and object 2. Now the entire design has a circular shape which makes it hard to eyeball with the given view commands. So i figured if I can rotate my view exactly around the radius of my object I'd get the best view to fix it.

You should just share that actual problem then, maybe your way of fixing the problem is not ideal, but you wouldn't know that if you just ask us how to fix a completely different problem like this. See XY Problem

Your idea that an easier method to fix my problem might be at hand is not incorrect. In the meantime I was able to do how I wanted to, the answer I posted as solution. But there would also be the option to just operate from top-view and hide all the unnecessary faces unless the ones I want to space. This is evenly tideous, however, so I will probably apply both ways into a workflow. Here a pic of the actual problem: https://postimg.cc/F1Rx29jv

@Jakemoyo, the question is weird and it sounds like an XY problem. Most likely there is no actual good reason to do this and whatever they are trying to achieve is done some other way... but technically, you can control view from Python and there would be no need for custom build to do that from an operator written in Python.

@Rabbit I think you are missing something here. This is not something that is usual to do and I suspect even though you found a "solution", your real problem might have better solutions. You should provide all context and detail about your original problem and it might save you a lot of effort and headache if someone provides a real solution to whatever this is.

@MartynasŽiemys hm, yeah I forget that the viewport operators are technically exposed via the API, just not shown in the info bar.

I don't mean viewport operators. Location, rotation, matrix - whatever you want. You can manipulate the view however you wish with Python.

So what did the trick was going to Edit/Preferences/Navigation/Orbit & Pan and there change the rotation angle, then put a dummy-object or an "empty" in the middle and lock view to that, then move the view by panning it to the start location, make sure you're in orthogonal view, and use the 4 and 5 on numpad from there. 64 presses equal a full rotation if you set the starting location carefully and change the rotation angle to 5+5/8.
